# Was baby head and elephant's body joined after Lord Ganesha was created by Shiva?

Tags: shiva, ganesha, shiva-purana

This video from a movie where he explains that baby head and elephant body was joined to form a God called Hanesha, is this story true?

> [Video Link regarding God Hanesha from a movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mevBcLYDRIs&feature=youtu.be&t=124)

[image]

Is this story true or fake, if true is there any proof regarding this in shiva Purana like the actor mentions in this video?

Comment: It's a fake story!

Comment: There is no scriptural reference. How one is supposed to answer your question? Could you help?

Comment: This is definitely fake as the body of an elephant cannot physically be compatible with a baby head.

Comment: @Wikash_, technically a elephant head isn't compatible with a human body.

Comment: In that case @Hanuman chailasa, an elephant's head should not be compatible with a human body.

Comment: It is @Wikash_ not me

Comment: Also @VectorMatrices it is not true simply because Movies aren't real.

Comment: "technically a elephant head isn't compatible with a human body" both statements are true hence Ganesh cannot be possible.

Comment: @Wikash_ We just believe in it, not over analyze the concept. Ganesha is a type of symbol since he represents multiple aspects of what we should have.

Comment: @VectorMatrices It is fine if you believe it but such a physically form is not possible.

Comment: Why do you put a bounty on this? This is obviously just something funny in a movie.

Comment: @Wikash_ could not stop thinking about it, that's why ..

Comment: @Amruth A Please select at least one of the answers below as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no scripture that explains the fact that a baby's head has been joined to create a god called Hanesha. This movie, called the "Director's Special", according to different [websites](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2995838/) and the about of the move, it is a comedy - drama. So the intent of the director was to try and make a joke. So we probably should not over analyze this.

Comment: You need to put a citation; please cite evidence.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @TheLittleNaruto that it is a fake story because that video is some movie movies are not real all the time. This movie is not very true, considering nothing in the scene that is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mevBcLYDRIs&feature=youtu.be&t=124) is true. Everything about this movie, even a search on the [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2995838/) will tell you that this movie is a comedy, making the movie not true.

Comment: Google search cannot be a source. Try to find a legitimate source. See [What kind of references are valid in answers? Are modern works allowed?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/596/what-kind-of-references-are-valid-in-answers-are-modern-works-allowed)